# Why $f(x)$ disappears in the probability exercise bellow?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, density-function

In the image bellow, in the solution part, why does $f(x)$ disappears from the first line to the second?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1O9r.png)

Comment: Hi! In the future, please typeset the mathematics. It's not that long. We can help you if you don't like the way it looks after your first attempt, but do please at least make the attempt, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because $X$ is a uniform-$(0,1)$ random variable. Its pdf, $f_X$, is defined by

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in (0,1) \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

It's also why you see the integral bounds change from $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$.

Comment: I missed that! Thanks a lot!